# Is it possible to capture traffic on host when using KVM passthrough?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, tcpdump

I have a KVM guest which uses PCI passthrough for its network interfaces:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
  </source>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
```

So there is no corresponding `ifcfg-xxxx` file on host machine. Also guest is a proprietary OS, there is no way to capture traffic on it.

It it possible to capture network traffic via tcpdump from these interfaces on host?

Comment: In that setup the host won't even know that it's a network interface. So what you need to look for is not a way to capture network traffic but rather a way to capture PCI bus traffic. I don't think it's possible, but I cannot say with certainty.

Comment: Yes I think so too. But maybe there is some KVM tool for this case.

Comment: You can capture traffic outside the host, but the host does not see any of it.